# Why are offsetHeight and offsetWidth intermittently inaccurate?

Tags: css, firefox, offsetwidth

I've been noticing that, at least in Firefox (haven't tested extensively in other browsers yet), the offsetHeight and offsetWidth properties on a `<div>` might be off by one pixel. (And yes, I'm already accounting for borders, padding, and margin.) Take a look at this screenshot to see what I mean:

[image: Here the total height with borders is 46px, but as Firebug shows the offsetHeight is only 45px]

So here the total ACTUAL height with borders is 46px, but as Firebug shows the offsetHeight is 47px (and without borders as 45px). Why the discrepancy? Is that a browser glitch? I should mention that the `<div>` in question has `float: left` set on it, and it also has some content inside of it that is similarly `float`ed`: left`.

Comment: Can you show the source markup and CSS?

Comment: I have observed something similar, and it happens only in Firefox, but never in Chrome or Edge. I see it in Firefox 88.0 for example. I am not using float, just a simple flexbox. Items in the flexbox sometimes report an offsetWidth that is 1 pixel less than the actual width.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your borders (and your math) again. You have a 1-pixel border on all sides of the div, which means a pixel on both the top **and** the bottom of the div.

1+1=2
45+2=47